# vlcj EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent does not resize to original size

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

Please have a look at the attached images. The vlcj media component hides the control buttons when the window is resized to original dimensions after maximizing.[image: vlcj inital] [image: vlcj full screen] [image: vlcj after resize]

```
public class PlayerVLCPanel extends JPanel {
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerComponent;

    public PlayerVLCPanel() {
        this.playerComponent = ComponentStore.getCameraStreamer();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(this.playerComponent.getVideoSurface(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class CameraJobControlPanel extends JPanel {
public CameraJobControlPanel() {
DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(this);

    layout.row().grid(expertDnLabel).add(expertDnField);
    layout.row().right().add(startCamButton, stopCamButton, startLazerButton, stopLazerButton).fill();
}
}

public class MainPlayerContainer extends JPanel {
public MainPlayerContainer() {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));

    add(topRegion()); // contains PlayerVLCPanel
    add(bottomRegion()); // contains the Control buttons    
}
}
```

Finally,

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Testing");
frame.add(new MainPlayerContainer());

frame.setLocation(100, 100);
frame.setSize(1050, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

How can I prevent this behaviour ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  Preferably using JSE components (no VLCJ).  2) Always call `pack()` immediately before `setVisible(true)`, which should be last.

Comment: BTW - what is a `DesignGridLayout`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson offtopic, but is it necessary the 'a'? MCTRE sounds better xD

Comment: @nachokk  Whatever works, is fine.  I prefer 'a MCTaRE' because I think of it (and say it in my head) as the name McTare.  Well, either that or a McDonalds burger sans the content (AKA a McBun).  But if I was ticking off the points in my head, I'd do it as 'an M-C-T-R-E'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sure, let me create one and post as soon as my work hours are over. And DesignGridLayout is a layout manager (https://designgridlayout.java.net/).